# How to disable moving down on Enter key in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007

There used to be a check-box in preferences in Excel 2003 to disable moving down on Enter key after you edited a cell. Where could I find that setting in Excel 2007?

<whining on>It drives me insane how microsoft trashes users skills and "fingers" memory to make what their new users may be will find easier. What about us, using these products for ten years?<whining off>

I want to control moving around with arrow keys, and Enter to only return me from the cell editing mode to navigation, not moving down. I'm not in a data entry business!! I'm analyzing data, editing just few cells time-to-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Office 2007 still has all the same options as previous version (for the most part).  When you can't find something you're used to in Office 2007, it's usually under the Office Button. :)

Anyhow, to change the Enter key behavior you need to access the Excel Options window. To do this you can click on the Office Button--> Excel Options (located at the bottom)--> Advanced.

The first entry under "Editing options" is where you can set up what the Enter key does.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2007 there isn't a way to set the  key's default to just accept the data and leave the cursor in the same place. Referring to [techie007](https://superuser.com/a/140808)'s answer you can make the cursor go up, down left or right. And, that sucks! That's the one main feature I miss most from the older versions of Excel.

However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: please note that the order of the answers changes so you shouldn't refer to an answer by direction (above/below etc) but refer to the poster's name.

Answer (score 2):

Excel in Office Professional Plus 2010:
File > options > Advanced > [] After Pressing Enter, move selections (up, down, right left) or not at all.